# Passing multiple marker locations from PHP into Googlemap jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I am trying to build a wordpress plugin that displays user locations on a googlemap. The address is geocoded and saved as a lat/long string to geo_address.

I'm then trying to retrieve that data and pass it to the Markers array used by googlemap.

The code to get the geo data is:

```
   $blogusers = get_users_of_blog();
   if ($blogusers) {
   foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
   $user = get_userdata($bloguser->user_id);
   $user_location = get_the_author_meta('geo_address', $bloguser->ID );

   $gLocations = '[User ID ' . $user->ID . ', ' . $user_location .'],';
```

I then try to add it to the marker array with:

```
   var markers = "[<?php $gLocations ?>]";
```

If I echo $gLocations it displays like a perfectly formatted marker array, but in gmaps it displays nothing.

The full gmap code is here http://jsfiddle.net/nE2Ge/

Comment: What does a "perfectly formatted marker array" look like?

Comment: what does json output look like. you say lat/long is string which doesn't make sense

Comment: The $gLocations output with echo looks like this:
[User ID 1, ], [User ID 43, 51.5784897,-0.02016619999994873], [User ID 44, 58.3498003,11.935649000000012], [User ID 45, 58.2234382,11.920179500000017],

Which as far as I know is the correct format for markers.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, your javascript 'markers' variable should be an array and not a string as you are creating like in your fiddle where you are using quote marks around your php to output the value of the markers variable is wrong. Secondly, what you commented is not a valid javascript array:

```
[User ID 1, ], [User ID 43, 51.5784897,-0.02016619999994873], [User ID 44, 58.3498003,11.935649000000012], [User ID 45, 58.2234382,11.920179500000017],
```

That will cause errors as strings must be quoted, where as you don't have quote marks around User ID 1 and such. So your php needs to be:

```
$gLocations = '["User ID ' . $user->ID . '", ' . $user_location .'],';
```

Or perhaps a dotEquals ( .= ) after $gLocations

Then when you output $gLocations to the view, inside the javascript code,

```
var markers = [<?php echo $gLocations ?>];
```

Also, you should probably add some checking whether markers[i][1] and markers[i][2] actually exist or not. Should also refine insertion of commas to $gLocations within the php code based upon whether or not $user_location is valid.

Comment: Thanks for a clear and concise answer! I amended the code and have some partial success. The map now shows just the last marker, and if I view source it shows that markers only lists one marker
 // Multiple Markers
    var markers = [["User ID 45", 58.2234382,11.920179500000017],];
    ;

How can I get this to display all the markers? As you can probably tell, I'm not exactly php expert...

Comment: You're welcome! Remember when I said "Or perhaps a dotEquals ( .= ) after $gLocations" ? Is $gLocations previously defined as a string prior to your foreach loop? If amending items to a string you need .= rather than =

Comment: $gLocations is only used after the foreach loop. If I use dotEquals there is no map content, and If I print_r $gLocations then it returns a lot of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing an echo when you create your JavaScript variable.  Without the echo nothing gets added to the markers var.  Try

```
var markers = "[<?php echo $gLocations ?>]";
```

You could also add a console.log(markers) to verify markers contains the correct markup.

```
console.log(markers);
```